# Write if functiodsadsadsadsad

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I need to style component with some conditionals....

See first my code

```
 margin: ${({ env }) => (env ? `100px` : `200px`)};
```

This is work nice, but i want to add one more coniditional

```
 margin: ${({ env, mobileVersion }) => (env ? `100px` : `200px` && mobileVersion '0')};
```

This is my example what i try  but no work...

What i need ? I need to add if env true 100px else 200px but if mobile version to set margin to 0 ? is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 margin: ${({ env, mobileVersion }) => (env ? `100px` : (mobileVersion ? '0' : '200px')};
```